# Can't Install Ubuntu 17.10 Due To Graphical Glitches

Tags: system-installation, amd-graphics, 17.10

Once I hit Enter on "Install Ubuntu" and it tries to switch to the GUI installer, the screen starts spazzing out in all sorts of creative and colorful ways, enough that the installer is entirely obscured. I've got an R9 390 graphics card, could that be causing the problem?

Comment: "  I've got an R9 390 graphics card, could that be causing the problem?"  Yes, but unlikely. Buggy installer/media might be more likely. So... thing to try... install the videocard driver you need from the live dvd and try it with that running.

Comment: I think it's most likely, check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967267/ubuntu-17-10-crashes-shortly-after-startup only thing we have in common system wise is the 390.

Where and how do I install the right drivers? I assume I probably need the mesa drivers but I'm clueless as to how to download them on linux

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem with your installation media. Well, You can try another installation media of Ubuntu or if you are using bootable USB drive, try to make it bootable again.

**Updated:**

Ok, try to install Ubuntu on on Vmware or Virtual box and check if it works or not?

Comment: I recently used this USB Drive to install Windows 10 and it worked perfectly fine; tried redownloading the Ubuntu .iso via torrent and putting it on again via Rufus but no luck, still running into the same graphical errors. Also it changes my Windows Time & Date every time I try to install it, which is kinda odd.

Comment: "Also it changes my Windows Time & Date every time I try to install it, which is kinda odd. "  Nope. Both systems change the BIOS clock. But both are NOT using UTC. And the fix is to set Windows correctly (Linux does it correctly ;-) )